# S/MIME for Mac and iOS

Tags: encryption, email, smime

I have been trying to generate S/MIME certificates for my MacOS and iOS devices and it does not seem to work. I have researched on this matter and it seems that keyUsage  and extendedKeyUsage are needed in order for it to work.

> These are needed to be inputed into openssl.cnf
>   [usr_cert]
>   keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
>   extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth,emailProtection
>   subjectAltName=email:move

I added these three line into `[usr_cert]` from `/System/Library/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf`

As in [CA_Default] it states x509_extensions = usr_cert

From there I am issuing the following commands

> openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca.key 4096
>   openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
>   openssl genrsa -aes256 -out cert.key 4096
>   openssl req -new -key cert.key -out cert.csr
>   openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in cert.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 00 -out cert.crt
>   openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey cert.key -name “email@address.com” -out cert.p12

After doing so I am getting the CA certificates and S/MIME certificates, but when I check to see if the keyUsage and KeyUsage Extensions are there with:

> openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.crt

they are not there.

I am editing the default openssl.cnf file

Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

Meta: this is OpenSSL, but not Mac specifically. Most things OpenSSL is used for are security related. I'd suggest tagging openssl.

Many of the settings in the OpenSSL config file, which defaults to a platform-dependent location like the one you specify but can be overridden, are used by default **only by the `req` and `ca` utilities**, the latter of which was created precisely to be a minimal CA and issue certs. The primary job of the `x509` utility is to display, examine, and convert certs; issuing a cert with `x509 -req -CA [-CAkey]` is an add-on that does not have all the features `ca` does. In particular it only adds extensions if you specify in the command line, not in the config file. (And it can't carry-over extensions from the CSR at all, although that doesn't seem to be a problem for you.)

**Solutions:** use `ca` with the desired settings in the config file, or use `x509 -req -CA [-CAkey]` with `-extfile [-extensions]` pointing to a file or section of a file with the desired extensions -- possibly but not necessarily the standard config file.

**Also:** 365 days is a pretty short lifetime for a CA cert. I think you want SAN `email:copy` instead of `move` because the one SMIME cert I've used personally (trial from Comodo) has my email in **both** Subject and SAN. You probably don't need `nonRepudiation` in (basic)KU; my cert doesn't have it, and in general the idea that publickey signatures could support non-repudiation was popular back in the 1980s but in practice it almost never worked so people have pretty much given up on it. OTOH I doubt it will hurt anything.

Comment: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/x509guide.txt has a few things to say about both nonRepudiation and email:copy vs email:move.